# Xpath syntax for HtmlAgilityPack row

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim cl As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim html As String = cl.DownloadString(url)
Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)

Dim table As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table']")

For Each row As HtmlNode In table.SelectNodes(".//tr")
   Dim inner_text As String = row.InnerHtml.Trim()

Next
```

My `inner_text` for each row looks like this, with different years and data:

```
       "<th scope="row">2015<!-- --> RG Journal Impact</th><td>6.33</td>"
```

Each row has a `th` element and a `td` element and I have tried different ways to pull the value but I can't seem to pull them one after the other by looping the column collection. How can I pull just the `th` element and the `td` element using the correct Xpath syntax ?

Until I can use better code I'll use standard parsing functions:

```
Dim hname As String = row.InnerHtml.Trim()
Dim items() As String = hname.Split("</td>")
Dim year As String = items(1).Substring(items(1).IndexOf(">") + 1)

Dim value As String = items(4).Substring(items(4).IndexOf(">") + 1)
If value.ToLower.Contains("available") Then
    value = ""

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry on with querying the row:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim h = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<table class=""table"">
<tr><th scope=""row"">2015<!-- --> RG Journal Impact</th><td>6.33</td></tr>
<tr><th scope=""row"">2018 JIR</th><td>9.99</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>"

        Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(h)

        Dim table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table']")

        For Each row In table.SelectNodes(".//tr")
            Dim yearData = row.SelectSingleNode(".//th").InnerText.Split(" "c)(0)
            Dim value = row.SelectSingleNode(".//td").InnerText
            Console.WriteLine($"Year: {yearData} Value: {value}")
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> Year: 2015 Value: 6.33
>   Year: 2018 Value: 9.99

Comment: A little tweet on the first split and it works like a champ.  Split("<")  got rid of the <!--.  Thanks